# IvyIDEA plugin doesn't download all the dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, ivy, intellij-plugin

I'm working on a project where ant + ivy are used for build process.

Since Intellij IDEA is my primary IDE for development I've downloaded IvyIDEA plugin in order to automate the process of resolving dependencies by ivy.

After a while I noticed that not all the dependencies were downloaded, some of them were, but some custom artifacts were missing. I checked the generated list of dependencies by plugin and some of them were actually missing thought the resolving process finished successfully:

```
report for projName compile produced in C:\Users\test\.ivy2\cache\projName-compile.xml
    resolve done (6375ms resolve - 156ms download)
post 1.3 ivy file: using exact as default matcher
post 1.3 ivy file: using exact as default matcher
post 1.3 ivy file: using exact as default matcher
post 1.3 ivy file: using exact as default matcher
post 1.3 ivy file: using exact as default matcher
post 1.3 ivy file: using exact as default matcher
post 1.3 ivy file: using exact as default matcher
No problems detected during resolve for module 'ProjName' [All configurations].
```

I started to dive into ivy logs generated by the plugin and saw this for a bunch of different dependencies:

```
Sort dependencies of : projToImport;1.1.85300.20210326.5 / Number of dependencies = 8
Non matching revision detected when sorting.  projToImportdepends on anotherProj;1.1.81201.20210326.1, doesn't match anotherProj;1.1.81201.20210406.1
Module descriptor is processed : junit#junit;4.11
....
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: when I do the same in Eclipse IDE with installed Ivy plugin, it all works and can I see all the dependencies described in ivy.xml This makes me think that my ivy-settings.xml and ivy.xml files are correct.

So, my assumption that IvyIDEA plugin doesn't work correct way or something. How is it possible to fix this?

My IveIDEA configuration:
[image: IveIDEA configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the version of ivy: the current version of IvyIDEA plugin (1.0.16) I used contained ivy 2.5.0 and I had to use ivy 2.4.0 in order to run my ivy-settings.xml\ivy.xml.

So the solution for me was to downgrade ivy to version 2.4.0.